# Get the name of the Generic (T in <T extends... >) in java

Tags: java, generics

I have a this class and method:

```
public class Runner<T extends Domain> implements Runnable {

public void run() {
   ...
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)
   ...
}
```

I need to execute the file and pass it the type of T as an agument (or some other string that will allow me to distinguish between diferent domains in the executed file, but T is a class that extends the class `Domain`, where `Domain` is an abstract class.

I thought about adding a static method that returns the name of the class and calling `T.getName();`, but this can not be done in abstract classes..

How should I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to access a given `T` in your `runFile` method, you can pass a `T` as an argument and reference it from there (for instance `t.getClass().getName()`). What you can't do is discover the runtime type of `T` within your `Runner` instance without an actual `T` instance to reference.

Comment: OK, Got it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the type into the constructor of the class:

```
public class Runner<T extends Domain> implements Runnable {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public Runner(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Use your class here
        String name = clazz.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh, the same solutions at the same time:)

Answer (score 2):

You can create the constructor for your class, in which you can pass the `Class` object and the use it:

```
private Class<T> clazz;

public Runner(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

// ...

public void runFile() {
    // do smth with
    clazz.getName()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`private void runFile(Class<T> classOfT) {...}`